# Error: Could not demultiplex stream video player opencv depth camera

Tags: opencv, video, stream

Video player gives "could not demultiplex stream"

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
pipeline.start(config)

# Define video writer for detection results
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out_detection = cv2.VideoWriter('detection_5.avi', fourcc, 30, (608, 480))

# Define video writer for normal video stream
out_normal = cv2.VideoWriter('normal_video_5.avi', fourcc, 30, (608,480))

# Load YOLO model
model = YOLO("/home/rushabh/Railway_bot/weights/best.pt")

# Object classes
classNames = ["car","bus", "auto"]

try:
    while True:
        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
        
        if not color_frame:
            continue

        # Convert images to numpy arrays
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        # Perform object detection
        results = model(color_image, stream=True)

        # Process detection results
        for r in results:
            boxes = r.boxes

            for box in boxes:
                # Extract bounding box coordinates
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)  # Convert to int values

                # Draw bounding box
                cv2.rectangle(color_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

                # Extract confidence and class name
                confidence = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100
                cls = int(box.cls[0])

                # Draw class name
                org = [x1, y1]
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                fontScale = 1
                color = (255, 0, 0)
                thickness = 2
                cv2.putText(color_image, classNames[cls], org, font, fontScale, color, thickness)

        # Write the frame with detections to the detection video file
        # out_detection.write(color_image)

        cv2.imshow('RealSense with Detection', color_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

finally:
    # Stop streaming
    pipeline.stop()

    # Release resources
    out_detection.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```